# Firefox error with Video JS

Tags: video.js

I am getting an error in Firefox (ver 22/23) that says:

Specified "type" attribute of "video/mp4" is not supported.  Load of media resource xxxxx failed.

Is this repairable?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. *We need more information.*

Answer (score 0):

It's all about MIME types. When you specify `type` attribute on your video source - you also need to make sure your server understands what that types of files actually mean.

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

Add these lines to your server's **.htaccess** file and you'll be up'n'running.

For any additional information related to video conversion/playback - check out [this article](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/video.html)