# Video.js jQuery disrupting video play/pause functions in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, html, moodle, video.js, microsoft-edge

I am trying to use video.js to prevent fast-forward, but allow rewind, for mp4 videos on a Moodle site. The following script works in Chrome and Opera, but not in Microsoft Edge:

```
window.onload = function() {
  if ($('iframe').length > 0) {

    $('iframe').ready(function() {
      var videoPlayer = $('iframe').contents().find('video')[0];

      var cssLink = document.createElement("link")
      cssLink.href = "https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.0/video-js.min.css";
      cssLink.rel = "stylesheet";
      cssLink.type = "text/css";
      $('iframe').contents().find('head').append(cssLink);

      videojs(videoPlayer, {}, function() {
        var vjsPlayer = this;
        $('iframe').contents().find('video').prop('controls', 'true');
        $('iframe').contents().find('div .vjs-big-play-button').html('');
        $('iframe').contents().find('div .vjs-control-bar').html('');
        $('iframe').contents().find('div .vjs-caption-settings').html('');

        var currentTime = 0;

        vjsPlayer.on("seeking", function(event) {
          if (currentTime < vjsPlayer.currentTime()) {
            vjsPlayer.currentTime(currentTime);
          }
        });

        vjsPlayer.on("seeked", function(event) {
          if (currentTime < vjsPlayer.currentTime()) {
            vjsPlayer.currentTime(currentTime);
          }
        });

        setInterval(function() {
          if (!vjsPlayer.paused()) {
            currentTime = vjsPlayer.currentTime();
          }
        }, 1000);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

In Edge, the desired effect is achieved (seeking forward does not change the time on the video, but seeking backward does), however, the play/pause functions are broken. If I have seeked an odd number of times in either direction, the video is paused and only plays when holding down the play button. If I have seeked an even number of times (including zero), the video plays but the pause button does nothing. [I get the same results in Firefox, and have posted a question about that as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864139/video-js-jquery-disrupting-video-play-pause-functions-in-firefox).

I tried to add a `type="video/mp4"` attribute to the video tag, but this had no effect on the problem.

Additionally, I have seen a [suggestion](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/805982/html5-video-playback-problem-ie-11-windows-8-1-invalid-source) to add `AddType video/mp4 .mp4` to the .htaccess file, but I'm worried about doing that in Moodle. The content of the .htaccess file is:

```
deny from all
AllowOverride None
Note: this file is broken intentionally, we do not want anybody to undo it in subdirectory!
```

What would the consequences be of editing this?

Are there any other suggestions for getting the mp4 videos working properly with Microsoft Edge?

Comment: Enabling the MIME type `video/mp4` is a requirement anyway to serve the files from your server.. http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Comment: @Pogrindis, does this mean that I should go ahead and edit the .htaccess file, or is there another way to enable the MIME type?

Comment: What web server are you running ? The steps are different for IIS than for Apache for example, but it can be done without the modification of the `htaccess` certainly.

Comment: @Pogrindis, I'm using Apache2. It looks like `video/mp4` is already listed in my `/etc/mime.types` file, so I'm assuming there is another place I need to make a change.